# typescript изменить имя свойства во время компиляции

Tags: typescript

Допустим есть интерфейс/класс:

```
interface Book {
   i:string;
   t:string;
   p:number
}
```

Но писать код с такими "не говорящими" именами сложно, можно как то в typescript изменить имена свойств **во время компиляции**?

Например:

```
 interface Book {
    @name('i')
    id:string;
    @name('t')
    title:string;
    @name('p')
    price:number
  }
```

Спасибо!

Comment: а зачем? ты хочешь просто минифицировать код?

Comment: @Grundy, хочу повысить читабельность и удобство разработки. Работать с первым вариантом сложно, приходится постоянно смотреть что есть что, это пример, но таких свойств много. Так данные хранятся в файле.

Comment: А чем тебе на нравятся полные имена? `id`, `name`, `price`? Зачем ты хочешь делать их `i`, `n`, `p`?

Comment: Так данные хранятся в файле. А писать рантайм конвертор не хочу по причинам производительности, просто хочу считать и привести к типу, ну и записать так же.

Comment: То есть, тебе приходит объект с полями `i`, `n`, `p`, а ты хочешь работать с ним как с `id`, `name`, `price`?

Comment: да, но "изменить имена свойств во время компиляции" - важное условие

Comment: как ты компилируешь все?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111662/discussion-between-grundy-and-valera-kvip).

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению декораторы работают только в runtime(пока что, думаю однажды можно будет). И если не копать глубже то можно решать проблему так:

```
const ID = 'i';
const TITLE= 't';
const PRICE = 'p';

interface Book {
   [ID]:string;
   [TITLE]:string;
   [PRICE]:number;
}

///....

const book:Book = getBook();
console.log(book[TITLE]);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

- имена читабельны
- нет конверторов
- нет оберток
- не нужно копаться в компиляторе

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать функцию `getBookId(book: Book)` и везде ее использовать.

```
function getBookId(book: Book): string { return book.i }
function getBookTitle(book: Book): string { return book.t }
function getBookPrice(book: Book): number { return book.p }
```

Comment: для каждого поля отдельную функцию? :)

Comment: ну, можно код сгенерить, если их много.

Comment: почему тогда сразу нужный код не сгенерировать?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если json есть, то его какая-то программа записала.
И в ней в исходнике не `i-n-p`, a она знает, как в них переводить.
Вот можно сделать генератор, который это "знание" возьмет и сделает код `.ts`.
Вот так ProtoBuf, например, работает.

Comment: @Grundy, думаю имеется ввиду что-то на подобии этого

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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

Comment: Так у вас там создается оберточный объект, который ранее: "А писать рантайм конвертор не хочу по причинам производительности"

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, это не конвертер по сути, а скорее обертка

Comment: a обертка дешевле конвертера? объект то всё равно добавочный создается.

Comment: я пример функций добавил

Comment: а зачем в файле короткие поля?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, конвертер копирует все поля, в новый объект, а в обертке только два поля новых добавляются с методами

Comment: Ну, если в реальном объекте их 26, ане 3, тогда да, обертка -- лучшее решение.